# rails update_attributes method return nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is the code:

```
def update
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to my_account_path
  else
    redirect_to account_path
  end
end
```

`@user.update_attributes` should return `true` or `false` when validation failes but it returns `nil`.

Using Rails 3.1.2 & Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: You can try to use update_attributes! in development to let Rails raise an exception to see what's wrong.

Comment: Even if it does return `nil` that wouldn't cause problems in this case since `nil` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: @flooo I have tried with `update_attribute!` it also return `nil`

Comment: @AndrewMarshall even if the validation passed it returns `nil`

Comment: @Anup No it doesn't. Either you or some gem is overriding the method, or some method it depends on (e.g. `save`) and not doing so correctly.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall How can I track the issue/problem where the methods is overriding because I haven't override the method

Comment: You can step through the debugger. I find it unlikely that any gem would actually do that, but it's possible. `update_attributes` is a well-tested method and such a gapping bug wouldn't make it into a release. Also, I assume you're using ActiveRecord? You should also update your Rails to 3.1.4, lots of bug fixes and security fixes.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I am not facing this issue always only when I passed skill_attributes `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` in `params[:user]` then it returns `nil`
`User` has_many `Skills`

Answer (score 1):

attr_accessible setup on the model?

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes

Comment: Yes I have used the attr_accessible

Comment: I mean is attr_accessible blocking you from setting via update_attribute?  Suggest checking the development logs

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when I run into issues like this I'll update change `update_attributes` to `update_attributes!` -- that can forces an immediate exception to be thrown and can point you at exactly why the value being returned is an error saving.

It *should* be returning false if the data isn't saved. [According to the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveResource/Base/update_attributes):

> If saving fails because the resource is invalid then false will be returned.

And here's this snippet from the rails source (note that `update_attibutes` calls `save` under the covers):

```
def save(*)
  begin
    create_or_update
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    false
  end
end
```

So it specifically returns `false`, not `nil` if there's a problem saving the record.